# Find the value of a complex number equation given that $\alpha^3 = 1$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: complex-numbers

I am given the fact that $\alpha^3=1$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$. With this in mind I have to find the value of the following equation:

$(1-\alpha)(1-\alpha^2)(1-\alpha^4)(1-\alpha^5)$

This is what I tried:

$\alpha^3=1$

$\alpha^3 - 1= 0$

$(\alpha - 1)(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)=0$; Solving this I found:

$\alpha \in \bigg\{1, -\dfrac{1}{2}+i\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}, -\dfrac{1}{2}-i\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2} \bigg\}$.

However, I don't see how this might help. So I tried to simplify the equation as much as possible:

$(1-\alpha)(1-\alpha^2)(1-\alpha^4)(1-\alpha^5)=(1-\alpha)(1-\alpha^2)(1-\alpha^3 \alpha)(1-\alpha^3 \alpha^2)$

$=(1-\alpha)(1-\alpha^2)(1-\alpha)(1-\alpha^2)$

$=(1-\alpha)^2(1-\alpha^2)^2$

$=\bigg[ (1-\alpha)(1-\alpha^2) \bigg]^2$

$=(1-\alpha^2-\alpha+\alpha^3)^2$

$=(1-\alpha^2-\alpha+1)^2$

$=(2-\alpha^2-\alpha)^2$

$=...$

$=6- 3\alpha^2-3\alpha$

$=3(2-\alpha^2-\alpha)$

$=-3(\alpha^2+\alpha-2)$

$=-3(\alpha+2)(\alpha-1)$

Aaaand, I'm stuck. I think I'm missing some key insight since I keep getting stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: If you know the value of $\alpha$, couldn't you just plug it into the other equation?

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated But $\alpha$ can take any of 3 values. Which one should I plug in? I am asked for one answer, one number. Not two or three. If I use the 3 values of $\alpha$ wouldn't I get three different answers?

Comment: @NoChance How exactly did you get those values? It is said that $\alpha$ is a complex number, that's why I got those 3 values for $\alpha$. I'm not sure I understand your question of 'What does this have to do with Complex Numbers?'. Well, $\alpha$ IS a complex number.

Comment: @BogdanVlad, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\alpha^3=1$ we have
$$(\alpha-1)(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)=\alpha^3-1=0,$$
but $\alpha- 1\ne0$ (because $\alpha\not\in\mathbb{R}$), so it must be that $\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0$.

Now, you have shown at one step that
$$(1-\alpha)(1-\alpha^2)(1-\alpha^4)(1-\alpha^5)=(2-\alpha-\alpha^2)^2,$$
so writing $2-\alpha-\alpha^2=3-(1+\alpha+\alpha^2)=3$ we see
$$(1-\alpha)(1-\alpha^2)(1-\alpha^4)(1-\alpha^5)=3^2.$$